# Run multiple versions of the same function independently in python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-multithreading

I currently have a for loop that creates a pandas dataframe on each iteration and launches a function where that dataframe is the argument for the function:

```
for ii in hold_:
        
 temp_df = runners_df[runners_df['market_id'] == ii]
 from odds import odds
 odds(temp_df )
```

Is there a way I can run the all the versions of the function called in the loop independently but concurrently. I want to add a variable time delay within the function, so some versions of the function in the loop may not finish for 5 hours, while some will finish almost instantaneously. Can I use threading for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/how-can-i-use-threading-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Threading would be the first thing to try. The code below should approximately work in your case. It creates a thread for each task. Depending on what your `odds` does, your code could be further enhanced with [muliprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), at the cost of increased complexity.

```py
from odds import odds
from threading import Thread


threads: list[Thread] = []
for ii in hold_:
    temp_df = runners_df[runners_df['market_id'] == ii]
    th = Thread(target=odds, args= (temp_df,), name=f"Thread #{ii}")
    threads.append(th)
    th.start()

for th in threads:
    th.join()
```